# JavaScriptCore borked strings – character encoding issue

Tags: javascript, macos, shell, character-encoding

I'm trying to use JavaScriptCore to do some string manipulation from the terminal, but I can't get past some sort of character encoding problem.

If I run this in Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc -e "print('héllo world')"
```

It should obviously print `héllo world`, but instead it prints `hÃ©llo world`. The same result happens if I run the print statement inside jsc interactive mode.

I know the gibberish text is an incorrect character encoding translation issue. The thing is, I can't figure out how to tell jsc to use a particular encoding. I've experimented with changing $LANG for my shell, but that has no effect.

Where is the encoding issue happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like JavascriptCode does not support UTF8 input files (which is what Terminal is supplying here).

Interesting to note that `node.js` does process your example correctly.

In your simple case, it may be possible to use the slightly extended 8 bit character set CP1252. I.e., if you put the above print command in a file `a.txt` and use `iconv` to  convert it:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t CP1252 a.txt >aa.txt
```

You can now run `jsc aa.txt` and you get the desired output (`héllo world`).

Another (inconvenient) option is to use Unicode code points directly in your strings. I.e., your example would look like this:

```
print('h\u00E9llo world');
```